# Drodown menu z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

i am working on this [website](http://birsmatt.ch/wohnungen/) and as you can see, by clicking on the blue buttons over the table, a dropdown menu appear.

As you can also can see the dropdown menu is displayed behind the table `thead`. How can i fix it?

I want to place the dropdown menu **over** the table thead.

Thanks in advice.

HTML:

```
<span class="dropdown open">
        <button aria-expanded="true" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Zimmer<br> Rooms
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">    
        <form class="filter">
                <input id="zimmer5" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 5.5
            <br>
                <input id="zimmer4" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 4.5
            <br>
                <input id="zimmer3" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 3.5
            <br>
                <input id="zimmer2" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 2.5
            <br>
        </form>
        </ul>    
        </span>
        <span class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Stockwerk<br> Floor
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">    
        <form class="filter">
                <input id="checkboxID" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> EG
            <br>
                <input id="checkbox1OG" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 1.OG
            <br>
                <input id="checkbox2OG" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 2.OG
            <br>
                <input id="checkbox3OG" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 3.OG
        </form>
        </ul>    
        </span>
        <span class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Haus<br> House
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">    
        <form class="filter">
                <input id="haus1" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 1
            <br>
                <input id="haus2" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 2
            <br>
                <input id="haus3" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 3
            <br>
                <input id="haus4" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 4
            <br>
                <input id="haus5" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 5
            <br>
                <input id="haus6" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 6
            <br>
                <input id="haus7" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 7
            <br>
                <input id="haus9" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 9
            <br>
                <input id="haus11" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 11      
        </form>
        </ul>    
        </span>    
        <span class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Bruttomiete<br> Gross Rent
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">    
        <form class="filter">
                <input id="range1" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 1200 – 1600
            <br>
                <input id="range2" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 1600 – 2000
            <br>
                <input id="range3" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 2000 – 2400
            <br>
                <input id="range4" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 2400 – 3000
            <br>
                <input id="range5" class="unchecked" type="checkbox"> 3000 – 3400
        </form>
        </ul>    
        </span>
```

Comment: That is a tough one. You may want to remove all the code not needed to replicate in your answer as well as include the relevant CSS.

Comment: `.dslc-module-front` seems to be the issue. Seems to fix this issue but cause other issues if you remove the position or z-index of it.

Comment: @Picademmerda thanks for accepting my solution! And btw. nice design you created! **thumbs up**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the z-index from class `.dslc-module-front`:

```
.dslc-module-front {
    position: relative;
    /* z-index: 0; */
}
```

**Update**

As mentioned by Goose, simply removing the `z-index` from a common class causes other problems, that's why you should add an additional depth info to the element containing the dropdowns.

```
div#dslc-module-54 {
  z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: That breaks other parts of the site. Look at the logo when you do that.

Comment: That new specifier still isn't specific enough, as that rule still applies to both the table parent and the logo. It appears to me the class can be removed entirely without unexpected results.

Comment: The question asker already changed the page and it seems the problem is now fixed so we can't replicate the problem anymore. Let's wait and see what has been changed to get rid of the problem. If the ID is used more than once in the page it should be rewritten to not use any duplicate IDs.

Comment: Ah, I misread your selector. Now I see you're using the ID, that should work too.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the answer is in the table that's on top, not trying to push the dropdown upwards. I saw this code.

```
.dslc-module-front {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

You could comment out the z-index to fix the issue, however this class is also used other places, such as the logo.

Removing this class for the `#dslc-module-20` element should fix the issue.

You should also check for any unexpected issues this might cause.